# How to add shadow to `<View>` like normal tab bar

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

This is my custom NavBar using `<View>`

[image]

Can I add bottom shadow like normal react-navigation bar (like image below)?

[image]

Adding shadow seems difficult to me

```
  header: {
    height: 55,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 5,
    },
    elevation: 4,
    zIndex: -1,
    overflow: 'visible'
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use CSS:

```
header: {
    height: 55,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOffset: {
        height: 1,
        width: 1
    }
}
```

Adjust values to your convenience. In some cases, you'll want to make sure you set an appropriate `zIndex` value and double check that your header `overflow` is `visible`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this didn't work for my case. I don't see the bottom shadow :(

Comment: Refreshed 5 times but nothing changes

Comment: Try adding a `zIndex` value to your header.  Also make sure your header `overflow` isn't `hidden`.

Comment: I see you use a negative `zIndex` value. Try a positive one, like `42`.

Answer (score 1):

your are not using width inside shadowOffset thats why you are not getting shadow.

```
shadowOffset: {
    height: 2,
    width: 2 
}
```